# About 1 in 5 posts (questions/answers) are removed from site. Can we have a breakdown of reason for deletion?

Tags: discussion

The **latest post id** is roughly **26600** at the time of writing.

- The number on the Site Stats panel on the front page shows that we currently have 6557 questions and 8745 answers on our site, or around **15300 *non-deleted* posts** in total.
- Apart from questions and answers, as far as I know, **tag wikis and tag excerpts** are also identified by post id. A quick query on SEDE shows that there are around **1500 posts** with PostTypeId = 3, 4 or 5.
- There are **a few gaps** in the progression, totaled up to around **6000 ids**: 934 → 1929 (996 ids, not accessible), 3974 (beta information), 4018 (site scope), 10160 → 11154 (995 ids, not accessible), 11751 → 12746 (996 ids, not accessible), 15640 → 16636 (997 ids, not accessible), 17353 → 18351 (999 ids, not accessible), 24612 → 25609 (998 ids, not accessible)
- As confirmed by [our community moderator](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/users/27/madara-uchiha), there are roughly **3700 deleted posts** in total.

It might be interesting in knowing why there are gaps in the ids, but that should belong on a different question. Ignoring the tag wikis and gaps, there are a **total of 19000 posts** ever posted on our site, and 3700 posts (around 19.5% of total number of posts) are deleted, which means roughly 1 in 5 posts are removed.

(While the numbers may not be frequently updated, at this scale, we can assume that the result of the calculation does not deviate too much from the actual number).

Can we have a breakdown of:

- The number of questions/answers deleted for each type?
- Tag distribution of the deleted questions?
- Are the questions deleted by roomba process, or are they deleted by manual delete votes (moderator or power user alike)?
- Closure status of the deleted questions?
- (... or anything interesting that might help us move the community forward?)

Comment: It's not easily possible to differentiate between roomba deletions and manual deletions (deletions aren't in SEDE, and site search doesn't let you search by "who deleted this thing"). JNat would probably be able to answer this, though, since he has magic employee powers.

Comment: @senshin: Some/All of the deleted posts are in PostsWithDelete table on SEDE. However, except for the post id, post type, parent post and creation/deletion date, all other information are wiped. The numbers also don't quite match up with my estimation.

Comment: Oh man, they [added that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/) since the last time I looked through the list of tables. brb writing queries

Comment: Mod searching for `deleted: yes` gave me 3,736 results. I don't know what the other 6k are, but they aren't deleted posts.

Nonetheless, even 3.7k is around 15% of all deleted posts, which is still disturbing.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I have asked about the other 6k on Super Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267921/what-are-these-mysterious-gaps-in-the-progression-of-post-id

Comment: Based on experience on another minor site, I'd say most of them are roomba'd because of off-topic/unclear (here mostly on speculative future events, bad identification request). Sometimes there are obvious NAAs by new users who can't comment and think this is a forum for discussion. However, this is only my personal opinion, since I'm nowhere near to mod tools.

Comment: @AkiTanaka: I completely agree with your observation, though it is better to have some concrete number to look at.